# Custom pg_hba.conf not copied to PostgreSQL Docker Container

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

**Issue Details**:

I have a custom `pg_hba.conf` file on my local machine, and I want to copy it to my PostgreSQL Docker container to override the default configuration. Here are the two solutions I've tried:

**Solution Attempt 1**: Using a Volume Mount in docker-compose.yml

In my `docker-compose.yml`, I added the following volume mount for my db service:

```
volumes:
  - ./pg_config/pg_hba.conf:/etc/postgresql/12/main/pg_hba.conf
```

This solution should copy my custom pg_hba.conf file to the PostgreSQL container. However, when I start the container, it doesn't seem to use my custom file, and the configuration remains unchanged. However, my local pg_hba.conf is reverted back to the same file that is being generated on the container. Super weird. Am I understanding volumes incorrectly?

`docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    env_file:
      - .env
    restart: "on-failure"
    depends_on:
      db:
        condition: service_healthy  # Wait for the db service to be healthy
  db:
    image: kartoza/postgis:12.0
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql
      - ./pg_config/pg_hba.conf:/etc/postgresql/12/main/pg_hba.conf
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: ${DATABASE_NAME}
      POSTGRES_USER: ${DATABASE_USER}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${DATABASE_PASSWORD}
      PGUSER: ${DATABASE_USER}
    restart: "on-failure"
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready" ]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5
volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

---

**Solution Attempt 2**: Creating a Separate Dockerfile for PostgreSQL

I also tried creating a separate Dockerfile for PostgreSQL (let's call it Dockerfile.postgres) where I set up the PostgreSQL image, added the custom pg_hba.conf file, and configured the database. However, even with this approach, my custom pg_hba.conf file is not being used when I start the container. The local file isn't getting reset this time, but the container file remains unchanged.

`Dockerfile.postgres`:

```
# Use the official PostgreSQL image as the base image
FROM kartoza/postgis:12.0

# Copy the custom pg_hba.conf into the container
COPY ./pg_config/pg_hba.conf /etc/postgresql/12/main/pg_hba.conf

# Set environment variables
ENV POSTGRES_DB=${DATABASE_NAME} \
    POSTGRES_USER=${DATABASE_USER} \
    POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${DATABASE_PASSWORD} \
    PGUSER=${DATABASE_USER}

# Expose the PostgreSQL port
EXPOSE 5432

# Set the command to run when the container starts
CMD ["postgres"]
```

`docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    env_file:
      - .env
    restart: "on-failure"
    depends_on:
      db:
        condition: service_healthy  # Wait for the db service to be healthy
  db:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql
    restart: "on-failure"
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready" ]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5
volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

---

**Question**:

I need help understanding why neither of these solutions is working as expected. How can I copy my custom pg_hba.conf file into my PostgreSQL container and ensure it is used for configuration? Thanks